# Weird resizing behaviour of QScrollArea with QHBoxLayout inside

Tags: c++, qt, qscrollarea, qlayout

How to reproduce: Create a new Qt Widgets Application and replace its `mainwindow.cpp` with the following:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QToolButton>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
    setCentralWidget(scrollArea);

    QFrame *scrollWidget = new QFrame;
    scrollArea->setWidget(scrollWidget);
    scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);

    QHBoxLayout *scrollLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    scrollWidget->setLayout(scrollLayout);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        QToolButton *button = new QToolButton;
        button->setText(QString(20, QChar('a' + i)));
        scrollLayout->addWidget(button);
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

After you build the project, the resulting app's window will refuse to be vertically shrunk below this:

[image]

**My question:** How do I get rid of the empty space above and below the buttons? I tried manipulating size hints, size policies, and everything else remotely relevant, to no satisfactory result. The only way to affect it seems to be to hardcode the `QScrollArea` widget minimum height, which is hardly useful in practice.

Comment: How do you want the widget to be displayed?

Comment: @eyllanesc Without the empty space directly above and below the buttons. I don't understand where it comes from - at first I thought these to be some configurable margins, but no.

Comment: If the height of MainWindow exceeds the height of the button plus the height of the sliders of the QScrollArea, how should it be seen?

Comment: MainWindow is resizable - note the handle in its lower right corner. The question is why it refuses to be vertically shrunk beyond this point.

Comment: I understand, you want to compress the size of QMainWindow also disappear those spaces, am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layouts use the `minimumSizeHint()` of the widgets as the minimum size, in the case of QScrollArea this is `QSize(70, 70)`.

This is the cause of the problem you see, in the case of the buttons `minimumSizeHint()` is `QSize(24, 23)`.

And as you say in your post a way to correct the above is to set the minimum size, for example I recommend using 48 as it is the minimum size of the button plus the QScrollBar:

```
QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
setCentralWidget(scrollArea);
scrollArea->setMinimumHeight(48);
QFrame *scrollWidget = new QFrame;
scrollWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 85, 0);");
scrollWidget->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
scrollArea->setWidget(scrollWidget);
scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
QHBoxLayout *scrollLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
scrollWidget->setLayout(scrollLayout);
scrollLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    QToolButton *button = new QToolButton;
    button->setText(QString(20, QChar('a' + i)));
    scrollLayout->addWidget(button);
}
```

*Note*: In addition to setting the minimum size I recommend placing the layout margins to 0.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for setting me in the right direction. A glance at `QAbstractScrollArea::minimumSizeHint()` implementation demonstrated a really weird algorithm that is either more clever than me or blatantly wrong. Given the blatantly wrong values it returns, it's probably the latter. Guess I have no other option but to override the minimum height here.